# SQL - Zeros being deleted when chaining CTEs

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I am using CTEs to calculate something in multiple steps, and I am having issues with preserving the rows that have a zero value for [Value].  Here is my code:

```
sum_values                              
AS (
   SELECT SUM([Value]) AS [Value]
        , [Situation]
        , [Category 3]
        , [Category 2]
   FROM #temp 
   GROUP BY [Situation]
          , [Category 3]
          , [Category 2]
),
rank_sums               
AS (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Category 3]
                                       , [Category 2] ORDER BY [Value]) AS [row]
        , [Category 3]
        , [Category 2]
        , [Value]
   --FROM #temp),               -- Taking from the temp table preserves the zero-rows.
   FROM sum_values),            -- Taking from the previous CTE does not.
```

As you can see from my comments above, the rank_sums CTE functions correctly when it takes values from a temp table, but not when it takes values from a CTE.  Here are the kinds of outputs I get from the two versions:

When taking from the temp table:

```
row    Category 3    Category 2    Value
1      C             A             -6
2      D             A             -4
3      E             B             0
4      F             B             1
5      G             B             3
```

When taking from the CTE:

```
row    Category 3    Category 2    Value
1      C             A             -6
2      D             A             -4
3      F             B             1
4      G             B             3
5      H             B             4
```

Does anyone have experience fixing this bug?

Answer (score 0):

Your `sum_values` CTE is calculating a sum; in the case you have shown, for Category 3 = "B" and Category 2 = "E", the zero is getting summed with a value of 1, and is therefore being eliminated.  When you select from `#temp` there is no summing, and so the zero appears.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The results tables I originally entered were incorrect, so the bug might be something else.  When I just execute the `SELECT` part of `sum_values`, I do get the row where Value = 0.